# They told me I couldn't rhyme "burj"

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> > An actor who danced to the time of my li',
> > an ancient invention, a wizard with y,
> > what most folk believe will come after you die.
>
> What am I?
>
> > Arabian city with sky-scraping burj,
> > marine trip for pleasure, vacation with splurge,
> > with treasure or scavenger; bloodhounds emerge.
>
> What am I?
>
> > With over or product; it's all yours to bear,
> > a video or water; with live, gulf or air,
> > a mauve plant on swamp; you can roast them and share.
>
> What am I?

What are we?

Comment: If that was the intended answer, then maybe it should have been on Halloween.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
An actor who danced to the time of my li',
an ancient invention, a wizard with y,
what most folk believe will come after you die.
```

> Swayze, pottery, heaven : GHOST. (A movie starring Patrick Swayze, with a famous scene involving a pottery wheel and ending with heaven.)

```
Arabian city with sky-scraping burj,
marine trip for pleasure, vacation with splurge,
with treasure or scavenger; bloodhounds emerge.
```

> Dubai, cruise, hunt : MISSION IMPOSSIBLE: GHOST PROTOCOL (starring Tom *Cruise* as Ethan *Hunt*; set partly in Dubai and released there)

```
With over or product; it's all yours to bear,
a video or water; with live, gulf or air,
a mauve plant on swamp; you can roast them and share.
```

> Cross, stream, marshmallow : GHOSTBUSTERS

All of these are

> movies with the word GHOST in the title, so "we" are *ghosts* or *movies* or *ghost movies*.

Comment: Again? Looks like this puzzle has been *busted* (oohhh... terrible) :D